# Trouble converting delphi objects with arrays to json

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I've been trying to translate my objects into a json string with TJson.ObjectToJsonString(object). It works fine for simple objects but it will break if the object contains an array(static or dynamic). What's the correct way of creating an json string of an object? I've looked at TSuperObject but it wasn't apparent what I would need to do.

Class structure

```
TPerson = class(TObject)
private
  FID       : integer;
  FLastName : string;
  FFirstName: string;
  FEmail    : string;
  fMyArray : array[0..2] of boolean;

  function ReadArray(i : integer):boolean;
  procedure WriteArray(i : integer; val:boolean);
public
  property ID       : integer read FID        write FID;
  property LastName : string  read FLastName  write FLastName;
  property FirstName: string  read FFirstName write FFirstName;
  property Email    : string  read FEmail     write FEmail;
  property MyArray[i : integer] :boolean read ReadArray write WriteArray;
end;
```

Example

```
  person := TPerson.create();
  person.ID := 25;
  person.FirstName := 'Homer';
  person.LastName  := 'Bologna';
  person.Email := 'Homer@Bologna.com';

  person.myArray[0] := true;
  person.myArray[1] := false;
  person.myArray[2] := true;

  str := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(person);//Access Violation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can persuade `ObjectToJsonString` to handle arrays, but they need to be arrays with type info. Your array uses an inline type, and they do not have type info.

For instance declare the field `fMyArray` like this:

```
type
  TPerson = class(TObject)
  private
    type
      TBooleanArray = array [0 .. 2] of Boolean;
  private
    FID: integer;
    FLastName: string;
    FFirstName: string;
    FEmail: string;
    fMyArray: TBooleanArray; // <-- this type has type info

    function ReadArray(i: integer): Boolean;
    procedure WriteArray(i: integer; val: Boolean);
  public
    property ID: integer read FID write FID;
    property LastName: string read FLastName write FLastName;
    property FirstName: string read FFirstName write FFirstName;
    property Email: string read FEmail write FEmail;
    property MyArray[i: integer]: Boolean read ReadArray write WriteArray;
  end;
```

A call to `ObjectToJsonString` produces this:

```
{"iD":0,"lastName":"","firstName":"","email":"","myArray":[false,false,false]}
```

Likewise, for dynamic arrays use

```
fMyArray: TArray<Boolean>;
```

rather than

```
fMyArray: array of Boolean;
```

for the exact same reason.

You might want to consider using a different JSON library though. The Embarcadero supplied library doesn't have the best of reputations.